# Minimum value of PA+PB+AB

Tags: geometry, optimization, maxima-minima

If $P(2,1)  $  and $A $ and $B  $ lie on $x$ axis and $y=x $ respectively,
then find the minimum value of $PA+PB+AB $ .

If $A$ was given , I could have worked geometrically, by using that image of $P$ and point $A$ and $B$ should be collinear. 
But here vary two things , $A$ and $B$....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, but we can work geometrically:

[image: Figure 1]

Simply reflect $P$ across the two lines.

Can you see what to do next?

Comment: why shall this oreintation be my minimum.

Comment: how will i get B and A

Comment: do you mean to join reflected points and solve with lines

Comment: This picture is, quite deliberately, not the minimum. It's a "generic" choice of points that happens to be fairly close to the minimum. Now, what does that reflection property tell us about the distances $P'A$ and $P''B$?

Answer (score 4):

Another way.

By Minkowski we obtain:
$$PA+PB+AB=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+1}+\sqrt{(y-x)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(1-y)^2+(2-y)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x-2+y-x+1-y)^2+(1+y+2-y)^2}=\sqrt{10}.$$
The equality occurs for $A\left(\frac{5}{3},0\right)$ and $B\left(\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4}\right),$ which says that $\sqrt{10}$ is a minimal value.